# Data Structure Parsing with System.IO.Pipelines

Tags: c#, .net, stream, buffer

So I've recently implemented the powerful `System.IO.Pipelines` feature in my .NET Core 2.1 socket server. It beautifully solves the "length problem", wherein you must make sure your buffer is large enough for the socket data.

There's a glaring problem for me, though. In the only example of Pipeline usage I can find, `\n` terminates each message, so the `PipeReader` (which is looping until an `0xa` has been located) "slices" the buffer at that single byte, `0xa`. But if I were to send UTF-8 strings, it's entirely possible that `0xa` would be the preceding length of the string. So the message would get passed at an incomplete point.

My solution is to design my protocol with what I call a "safety" byte (such as `0x31` immediately preceding/proceeding) to signal a true message termination.

Whereas in `Streams`, and dare I say, regular `byte[]` buffers, you could `Peek()` at the next byte and check the next byte, without advancing the reader. However I'm pretty sure `System.IO.Pipelines` has no such ability.

I suppose one remedy would be to slice it at the `\n`, when detected, and evaluate the resulting buffer's first byte. But this feels like it defeats a lot of the strength of pipelines (though maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Could you not call the overload of AdvanceTo specifying consumed+exmanined such that you don't yet consume the newline? This way you get it AND it's next character in the subsequent read? This is my understanding never having used pipelines but after reading the article introducing pipelines, msdn documentation and Marc Gravells two part blog

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Actually the current code doesn't consume the newline, just every byte leading up to it. Hence why in the article's example code, they start the Next buffer at position '1'. The fundamental problem is being able to check the value of the byte preceding/proceeding `\n` That said, I haven't seen that other blog yet..

Comment: Right, but by starting at position 1 you are in effect consuming position 0. So if posN=newline and N!=length you can just look at the next since you have it already. Otherwise if N==length then you can "ignore" it for now and indicate you've consumed N-1 and examined N. Your next read should start at the newline byte and then you can look at the next position. Unless I'm misunderstanding things